# Replace a private service in the Symfony container for testing

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, integration-testing

Is it possible to replace a private service in the DI container? I need to do this in my test environment, so that I can run integration tests but still mock HTTP calls to external APIs.

For example, I have this code that sets the mock for the HttpClientInterface:

```
$response = new MockResponse('"some json body"');
$client = new MockHttpClient([$response]);
self::$container->set(HttpClientInterface::class, $client);

// Execute controller / command and perform assertions
// ...
```

I have already tried to define the HttpClientInterface as a public service for my test environment with the config below, but this does not work as it isn't instantiable (it's an interface).

```
services:
  Symfony\Contracts\HttpClient\HttpClientInterface:
    public: true
```

Comment: You should mock not the `HttpClient`, but the service that depends on `HttpClient`. I imagine you have a service that encapsulates the logic of calling these external APIs, and that that service uses `HttpClient`, right?

Comment: The service that depends on the `HttpClient` is an API class that mediates comms with the external API. It has behaviour in it that I think should be covered by the integration tests (transforms responses from the external API etc.). I want to push mocking right to the outermost edges of the app so as much of our app code is tested as possible. Is this the wrong way of thinking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue myself for my specific case by creating my own MockHttpClient class that doesn't require setting the responses in the constructor. Replacing a service in the container at runtime seemed to be the wrong way to go based on how Symfony have intended for the container to be immutable